# remove the Quotes( ' ' ) from the value retrieved from the xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have my XML like this

```
 <P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0pt">
        <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman';  FONT-SIZE: 36pt FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 25pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'COMIC SANS MS'; FONT-SIZE: 6.7pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Form</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;TEXT-DECORATION:underline">10-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'CURSIVE'; FONT-SIZE:14pt">Hisasdf @ adsfkej % adsfkj-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Edwardian Script ITC'; FONT-SIZE:18pt">Singhaniadf kurmad-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE: 7pt">anurag arya fateh ali khan-Q</SPAN>
            <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Times New Roman'; FONT-SIZE:12pt;TEXT-DECORATION:underline">rakesh kumar sinfhania</SPAN>
      </P>
 <xsl:variable name="Fface">
    <xsl:value-of select="(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-FAMILY:'),';')))"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and I using this code to identify the font family and its working fine and gives me the value using this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Fface"/>
```

but value I got is `'TIMES NEW ROMAN'`having quotes but I want it without these quotes 
so what to do is there any procedure to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were sure that the apostrophes were always going to be present, you could just use the substring function to do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($Fface, 2, string-length($Fface) - 2)" />
```

Comment: Wow it works actually i m trying the translate() api to perform this but i found that it can't convert the output..
but your one wrks for me thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use the translate function to remove apostrophes from the value, you could do it this way:

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate($Fface, "&apos;", "")' />
```

This would remove ALL apostrophes from the value though, not just ones at the beginning at end.

Do note how the use of aposotrophes (') and quote marks (") have been reversed in the above statement to what is normally done.

If you did want to put it all into one big statement, you would do it like this, although it wouldn't be that easy to read.

```
<xsl:value-of select='translate(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,"FONT-FAMILY:"),";")), "&apos;", "")' />
```

Comment: its creating problem when i using this as whole

  `<xsl:value-of select="'translate(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(@style,'FONT-FAMILY:'),';')), "&apos;", "")'" />`

what to do if i want to write this in a single line